# The damaged QR Code

Tags: mathematics, logical-deduction, number-theory

Consider the following **pixel puzzle** which somehow looks like a **damaged QR Code** with clues on the left of every row and on the top of every column.

[image]

These numbers represent the **total amount of "black pixels"** within the respective row or column. Counting the black pixels suggests that **some of them are missing**.

Your first two objectives:

1. **Reconstruct** the QR Code by using the clues on the left of every row and on the top of every column.
2. **Scan** the QR Code.

The QR code yields a **code**. Your **third and last** objective is to transform this code into a **pandigital number** by using just **one simple arithmetic operation**. What pandigital number do you get?

**Definition**: *Pandigital number*

A pandigital number is one that contains each of the digits from $0$ to $9$ exactly once. The leading number must not be a $0$!

You can also download a MS Excel Sheet with the damaged QR Code matrix: https://github.com/stackmazer/Puzzling.Stackexchange/blob/master/Damaged_QR.xlsx

Comment: could you put some google excel form or csv?

Comment: @Oray  https://github.com/stackmazer/Puzzling.Stackexchange/blob/master/Damaged_QR.xlsx

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The final answer is:

> 9814072356

To fill in the QR code,

> I placed a "1" in each black square, then wrote excel equations counting the number of squares still required in each row/column. Then I filled in individual squares (by setting them to 1). First, I finished the squares in the top-left, top-right, and bottom-left corners, then by placing squares in rows where there was only one valid column left (and vice-versa). There was only one place where I had to guess, but apparently I guessed right on the first try.
>  
>  The final QR code is here:
>  [image]

Scanning the finished QR code gives us:

> "99066" in plaintext, which, when squared, gives us the pandigital number 9814072356.

Comment: Congratulations! You got it right! $\color{green}{\checkmark}$ "There was only one place where I had to guess" (Un-)Fortunately, QR Codes are very resilient :-)